# Rules for keeping a Rudraksha

Tags: scripture, shiva, shaivism, rudraksha

Recently I happened to visit the Shri Kashi Vishwanatha temple. There the priest gave a single Rudraksha bead.

I would like to know about the rules that are required to be followed to keep/ maintain the bead?

Be it sourced from Puranas or Shaivagamas.

For example, where must it be kept in the open or the closet? How to prevent it from getting impure/ spoiled due to dust etc. must it be worshipped daily? If not possible then what leeway is granted.

---

Please note: I am not asking about the rules to wear a Rudraksha, for which a question already exists. I am asking about simple maintenance of a single Rudraksha bead.

Comment: Single Rudraksha meaning one faced? or is it five faced? Usually one who wants to stay in Samasara must not wear the Eka Mukhi Rudraksha.

Comment: @Rickross Hiii<3. It is panchamukhi. Currently I have kept it in the open on Tirupati Balaji’s photo. Means ekamukhi kills or gives moksha? And Im not yet inclined to wear it, simply to protect and keep away from all dirt and sweat while travelling or whatever else. Just want to keep it normally.

Comment: Yes after a long time :) ,, it gives Moksha, does not kill but it takes you away from family life so not recommended for everyone

Comment: @Rickross Oh. No no, that’s scary, as yet.

Comment: Yes and that's why not suitable for all